# IF ELSE condition in Windows CMD

Tags: windows

I'm trying to check for a service running on a particular port number, if it is running i need to print "RUNNING" else i need to print "FAILED".

I am able to achieve it using Linux but not with windows CMD

Eg: Linux :

```
if netstat -na | grep 5095 | grep LISTEN ; then echo "RUNNING" ; else echo "FAILED" ; fi
```

I am trying to achieve same thing using windows CMD

I am very weak with windows CMD.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like following:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set file="C:\temp\a.txt"

netstat -na | findStr LISTEN | findStr 5095 > c:\temp\a.txt

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% GTR 0 (
  echo "Running";
) else (
  echo "Failed";
)
```